# Result of xpath expression is object and should be element

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver, screen-scraping

i'm new to scraping websites and i've been attempting to scrape google images using python (ultimately to make a discord bot but thats irrelevant). I did the following code to store the image src's as a list so I can pick an index and display an image (I tested it using xpath helper chrome extension and it returns what I need):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_path =r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
chromedriver_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=pepega&rlz=1C1GIWA_enGB617GB617&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1e6b-YfhAhWRs3EKHeKmAqoQ_AUIDigB&biw=2560&bih=947")

review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img/@src")

print(review)
```

The error i'm getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\tessst.py", line 8, in <module>
    review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img/@src")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 410, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img/@src" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.75)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I assume this is due to the xpath query as it says it should be an "element", however as i'm new to this, I have no idea how to return the image SRCs as an element. Can someone tell me how to fix my query so it won't show an error when in python? Thank you

Edit: I think ive got it doing what I want, id like to say thanks for the help everyone. What ive done is probably primitive by your standards but ill share it just in case it helps people :)

final code:

```
import nltk
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_path =r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
chromedriver_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=pepega&rlz=1C1GIWA_enGB617GB617&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1e6b-YfhAhWRs3EKHeKmAqoQ_AUIDigB&biw=2560&bih=947")

review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img")

imglist = []

for x in review:
    if x.get_attribute("src") != "":
        temp = str(x.get_attribute("src"))
        if temp[0:8] == "https://":
            imglist.append(str(x.get_attribute("src")))


print(imglist)
```

Just occurred to me that nltk isn't used (I was playing around with it at some point and forgot to remove it)

Comment: Can you edit into your question the full HTML of your webpage or its URL? That is the only way I know of to troubleshoot an xPath.  Your xPath must be finding an attribute; I suspect the culprit might be `@src`.

Comment: How many srcs' you are expecting on this page? Do you consider only the elements with src or you want to add data-src when src is not available?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I am stupid and only now noticed your URL is in the script; I can confirm that your xpath is finding the `src` attribute of your `img` element.  The following should find that element and then get its src attribute.

```
review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img")
```

This returns 100 elements.  I'm not sure what you want to do with the sources, but here's some code to simply print each:

```
for x in review
    if x.get_attribute.src != "":
        print(x.get_attribute(“src”)
```

This should print the `src` attribute for the 55 elements that have `src` specified.

Comment: Hi, I tried this today and it says that WebElement object has no attribute src. I'm not sure if this helps but I printed what was in review after the change to the xpath and got data such as the following "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e28a829e60ad43b89c590567310252d6", element="0.9472604356310186-1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e28a829e60ad43b89c590567310252d6", element="0.9472604356310186-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e28a829e60ad43b89c590567310252d6", element="0.9472604356310186-3")>"

Comment: Would you mind editing the latest version of your code into the question?

Comment: I’m curious, what did you change to get rid of that error?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the original code to show what I did. Basically I used the response that this reply is to and then changed x.src as this wasn't working in python to x.get_attribute("src")

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `src` attribute in a xpath that is what you are missing.However what i observe some of the image not having `src` attribute.Instead of that it is having `data-src` attribute.Here is your solution.Hope this helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_path =r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
chromedriver_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=pepega&rlz=1C1GIWA_enGB617GB617&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1e6b-YfhAhWRs3EKHeKmAqoQ_AUIDigB&biw=2560&bih=947")


reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jscontroller ='Q7Rsec']/a/img")

list_review=[]
for review in reviews:
   if review.get_attribute("src") is not None:
        list_review.append(review.get_attribute("src"))
print(list_review)
print(len(list_review))
```